# Alert button is not responding

Tags: javascript, button, alert

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Project 506</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#first").click(function () {
          alert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
        });
     });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Message Boxes</h1>
    <input type="button" id="first" value="Just a Notification" />
    <input type="button" id="second" value="Successfully Completed!" />
    <input type="button" id="third" value="Something Went Wrong!" />
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I show the alert box when I have clicked on `#first`? I'm not sure what is wrong with this code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: As above, now that the question is formatted properly, it's obvious that you haven't included the library jQuery.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery, you have to include it. Please [read the jQuery tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: You need to include jQuery library before using jQuery ^^ as stated already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add the jquery library on your code. You need to include the jquery script in your code inside the head or body for make your code working.

Jquery

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Only one argument is allowed in the `alert()` function. If you use more than one argument , the first argument before the comma will be used.

Here's your code

```
alert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error"); //this will alert oops..
```

Updated code

```
alert("Oops...Something went wrong! error");
```

I saw your using the sweet alert.js in your code. If you want the sweetalert instead of  native alert box . You need to use replace your code with the below one. Commas are allowed in sweet alert

```
sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
```

See the updated code :) :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project 506</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#first").click(function () {
                alert("Oops...Something went wrong! error");
            });
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Message Boxes</h1>
    <input type="button" id="first" value="Just a Notification" />
    <input type="button" id="second" value="Successfully Completed!" />
    <input type="button" id="third" value="Something Went Wrong!" />
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

See the js fiddle [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/189v9Lfw/)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot !

Comment: *"You are not allowed to put a comma inside the native alert() function. Only one argument is allowed. "* Well, you are certainly *allowed* to do this, it just ignores any but the first argument.

Comment: it accepts only one argument , that means more than 1 is not allowed... if you put more than 1st argument will be used and rest of the arguments are ignored,   @FelixKling

Comment: Right, but "not allowed" sounds like there would be an error of some sorts. But as you said, they are just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery library is missing inside head tag of your HTML Document.
include between `<head>` and `</head>` tags.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your HTML file should look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project 506</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#first").click(function () {
                alert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
            });
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Message Boxes</h1>
    <input type="button" id="first" value="Just a Notification" />
    <input type="button" id="second" value="Successfully Completed!" />
    <input type="button" id="third" value="Something Went Wrong!" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily putting Commas outside the string quotes in the alert. Also you can write the script code before the closing **body tag** instead of writing it in the **head tags**. This will definitely work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#first").click(function () {
            alert("Oops... , Something went wrong! , error");
        });
});
```